# Como clonar repositório GIT com todos os branches e tags

Tags: git

No GIT seria possível ao clonar um repositório o mesmo já baixar todos os *branches* e *tags* Haveria um único comando para isso, sem a necessidade de criar um *shell script*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quando você entra com o comando `git clone <repositorio>`, ele automaticamente baixa as branches junto com a tag.

Você pode verificar usando:

```
git branch -r


git tag
```

O remote também vem configurado como origin e você pode acessar usando:

```
git remote -v
```

Agora se você ir no Github e clicar no Download Zip, ele não irá carregar o git consigo, então retornará: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Se você estiver com dúvidas de como funciona e quais são os argumentos que o git clone aceita, acesse: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone

Answer (score 4):

```
$ git remote update
$ git pull --all
```